# CSS - style edit

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my wordpress site I use List category post plugin.
This is html code:

```
[catlist name=Ostatné numberposts=50 name_class=velkost
catlist thumbnail=yes force_thumbnail=yes catlist thumbnail_size=200,150 thumbnail_class=lcp_catlist
excerpt=yes excerpt_size=10 excerpt_class=moj_excerpt]
```

And this is CSS code:

```
.shrtthumbsd{
margin-bottom: 50px;

}

.shrtthumb {
float: left;
margin-left: 50px;
padding: 55px 15px;
    display: inline;
width: 100%;
}

ul.lcp_catlist {
font-size: 22px;
}

.moj_excerpt{
font-size: 18px;    
}
```

And it looks like this: https://www.akosizarobitpeniaze.sk/vsetky-clanky

I would like to align picture to the right side and have title of article (without bullet/dot) and excerpt under title.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your site.

```
.lcp_catlist li { list-style: none !imporant; }

.lcp_catlist li img { margin-right: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: I can not save the firts line (wordpress have issue with "!". Second line of CSS you sent moved pictures to the right but did not deleted bullets and there are still big gaps between text. It is live on link I provided.